# "Falling forces"

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-fall

First, I'm completely ignorant in physics, that's why I need your help and I'm sorry if I don't have a proper technical language.

I was trying to understand the forces that play a role during a fall when climbing. In particular, the carabiners indicate the maximum force in kilo-Newtons ($kN$) a carabiner can carry before break (e.g. $22 kN$).

Reading on Wikipedia I understood (I think) how to calculate the force ($N$) of my body.
$$1 kg = 9.81 N$$
$$75 kg * 9.81 N/kg = 735.75 N = 0.736 kN$$

Now I know that my body, if I stand on Earth, has a weight of $0.736 kN$. This is nice but not really useful to me, because what I want to calculate is the force on the carabiner if my body is in free fall for, for example, 6 metres.

Can anyone teach me the topics I need to know and help me to understand how to find the proper formula? Thanks!

Comment: You're actually not calculating it correctly, though you do arrive at your correct weight (in kilonewtons - kN). But I don't think someone can answer your question without knowing how elastic your rope is (if it were perfectly unstretchable, the force you're looking for would be infinite).

Comment: The equations you need are all found within those from projectile motion. As @stafusa mentioned, you simply need the distance over which your rope will allow you to decelerate. Then you solve for the acceleration this would require, multiply by your mass, and add in your weight. That should give you the force you exert on the carabiner. For the record, $6m$ is a fairly long fall and is likely to result in personal injury even if the carabiner holds. You should give serious consideration to not falling that distance

Comment: However, if this fall is unavoidable, I can say with almost 100% certainty that having the carabiner is better than not

Comment: @stafusa Now that you let me think about it, I totally missed the rope in my reasoning. Which kind of data do I need? The "stop force" in Kn declared by the manufacturers? A Petzl rope, for example, has a 8.6 Kn stopping force

Comment: @Jim It's better not falling at all! :D If I'm 75 kg and I'm 3 meters above the last carabiner (= the last anchor point) it means I'm gonna fall for 6m, right? So, if I know that a rope has a 8.6 Kn stopping force, how can I put all this data together to calculate the Kn on the last carabiner? I'm sorry if I appear like a kid that needs to be feed by mom

Comment: Brigo, @Jim 's comment has all you need to find the solution: you would need to find by how much the rope will extend when subjected to a sudden load in order to proceed with the calculations. It might be, though, that the information you search is already given in the  technical specifications of the rope. That might be relevant: https://www.petzl.com/NL/en/Sport/Forces-at-work-in-a-real-fall

Comment: @stafusa The link you linked is really cool! But it gives me the solution without the process. Based on Jim's answer, if the rope above the anchor point is 3m, I should make something like: 3 m * 75 kg + 735.75 N = 960.75 N = 1 Kn...is it right?

Comment: Brigo, sorry, but I won't have time follow on at the moment. If no one answers, you might want to consider posting in [​some other Physics website](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/391/75633), ​such as​ the [PhysicsForums](https://www.physicsforums.com/forums/homework-and-coursework-questions.152/).

Comment: In free fall, gravity accelerates you to some top speed. What we mean by "how much the rope extends" is how much give the rope has after the 6m fall; when the carabiner starts to catch you. You're going to go from some top speed to zero and while you decelerate, the rope is going to stretch a bit. This might be a few centimeters or a few millimeters depending on how stretchy it is. The total time to decelerate is an indication of how much force you experience. If it takes you 0.1s for the rope-carabiner system to bring you to a stop, the carabiner has to provide more than 8.1kN of force

Comment: the stretchier the rope, the more time you have to decelerate after the fall and the less force put on the carabiner

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force on carabiner from free fall](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/72867). See also [Calculating impact force for a falling object?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33834)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As first approximation a person falling in climbing is subjected to

$$
F_{stop} = \sqrt{2*g*m*k*\frac{Q}{L}}
$$

where k represents the elasticity of the rope, Q is length of the fall and L the length of the rope.
The carabiner will be subjected to a force equal to $2F_{stop}$.
In case of perfectly vertical fall and no friction.
Have in mind that 22kN is not a random choice but is twice the maximum force a human body can absorb without major damages... carabiners are designed to break at 22kN.

You should find out the derivation of the formula in this article:
W. Dan Curtis. Taking a Whipper – The Fall-Factor Concept in Rock Climbing, The College Mathematics Journal, March 2005, Vol. 36, No. 2

Comment: -1 Where has your equation come from? Have you derived it or copied from somewhere? How do you define *stiffness*? How can you find the *stiffness* of the rope from its technical specification?

Comment: Please note that the downvote is not an indication that we think you are wrong. It's more that this answer does not explain the concepts behind itself. The equation you list is not something common, like $F=,a$, which we wouldn't ask for a derivation of. To properly understand your answer, and for us to properly vet it, it would be helpful to include a description of where this comes from, why it works, what everything physically represents and how to determine those values. Expand on this a bit and I'm sure people will give their support

Comment: -1. Doesn't pass the smell test. Clearly this must depend on the mass of the climber.

Comment: @Chris of course I forgot the mass